# How can I create an m:n relationship not using the primary key in NHibernate?

Tags: database, nhibernate, orm, mapping, relationship

Assuming I had the following tables:

[image: Diagram of 3 tables: Publishers and Articles connected by a reference table named PublisherArticles]

If I now set up a many-to-many relationship in NHibernate, the `<key column />` attribute below will map the `PublisherArticles.VersionIndependentArticleId` to the primary key column of the article class (`Id`) instead of `VersionIndependentId`.

```
<class name="Article" table="Articles">
    <id name="Id" />
    <property name="VersionIndependentId" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Version" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Text" not-null="true" />

    <set name="Publishers" table="PublisherArticles">
        <key column="VersionIndependentArticleId" />
        <many-to-many class="Publisher" column="PublisherId" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Is there any way to target the `Articles.VersionIndependentId` column instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `foreign-key` property.

However, the model shown in my question does not work with NHibernate (it's actually a multi-m:n relationship: the m side of the relationship is not a unique record but a key shared by multiple records).

I'm not sure if this is bad normalization, just a limitation of my ORM or something else.